# Form validation errors not being echo'ed when attempting to insert a new record

Tags: php, mysqli

My form inputs records if I format the form fields according to the regex I have established and then echo's the record being inserted into the database successfully.  If I make any errors, it simply erases the fields and doesn't echo the error.  I'm fairly new to php and I'm doing this for a class project as part of an online course.  I'm not sure where my error is.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang = "en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
    <title>Tech Order Department.html</title>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8" />

<style>

div {
    text-align: justify;
    }

.section {
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     width: 70%;
    }
</style>

</head>

<body>

<h2>Tech Orders</h2>

<br>

    <title>Page Title</title>

    <h2>New Project</h2>

<p class="first"><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>
    <form action="http://www.oldgamer60.com/Project/try.php" method="post">

<div class="fieldset">
        <fieldset>

        Project: <input type="text" name="Project" value="<?php if(isset($Project)){ echo $Project; } ?>">
        <span class="error">* <?php if(isset($ProjectErr)){ echo $ProjectErr; } ?></span>
        <br><br>
        Client: <input type="text" name="Client" value="<?php if(isset($Client)){ echo $Client; } ?>">
        <span class="error">* <?php if(isset($ClientErr)){ echo $ClientErr; } ?></span>
        <br><br>
        LastName: <input type="text" name="LastName" value="<?php if(isset($LastName)){ echo $LastName; } ?>">
        <span class="error">* <?php if(isset($LastNameErr)){ echo $LastNameErr; } ?></span>
        <br><br>
        DateReceived: <input type="text" name="DateReceived" value="<?php if(isset($DateReceived)){ echo $DateReceived; } ?>">
        <span class="error">* <?php if(isset($DateReceivedErr)){ echo $DateReceivedErr; } ?></span>
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 
     </fieldset>
    </div>
    </form>
<br>        

<?php
function test_input($data){
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
}

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "xxx";
$password = "xxx";
$dbname = "oldga740_SeniorProject";

// create connection
$connection = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !$connection->connect_error){
    // to track errors
    $error = false;

    // now validate input fields
    if (empty($_POST['Project']) || !isset($_POST['Project'])){
        $ProjectErr = "Project name is required";
        $error = true;
    }elseif(!preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9.-]+$/",$_POST['Project'])){
        // check if project only contains number, letters, comma's periods and whitespace
        $ProjectErr = "Only letters, numbers, comma's, periods and white space allowed";
        $error = true;
    }else{
        $Project = test_input($_POST['Project']);
    }

    if (empty($_POST['Client']) || !isset($_POST['Client'])){
        $ClientErr = "Client name is required";
        $error = true;
    }elseif(!preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9.-]+$/",$_POST['Client'])){
        // check if project only contains number, letters, comma's periods and whitespace
        $ClientErr = "Only letters, numbers, comma's, periods and white space allowed";
        $error = true;
    }else{
        $Client = test_input($_POST['Client']);
    }

    if (empty($_POST['LastName']) || !isset($_POST['LastName'])){
        $LastNameErr = "Last name is required";
        $error = true;
    }elseif(!preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9-]+$/",$_POST['LastName'])){
        // check if last name only contains letters and whitespace
        $LastNameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
        $error = true;
    }else{
        $LastName = test_input($_POST['LastName']);
    }

    if (empty($_POST['DateReceived']) || !isset($_POST['DateReceived'])){
        $DateReceivedErr = "Data received field is required";
        $error = true;
    }elseif(!preg_match("/^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$/",$_POST['DateReceived'])){
        // check if data received only contains letters and whitespace
        $DateReceivedErr = "Date must be entered as YYYY/MM/DD";
        $error = true;
    }else{
        $DateReceived = test_input($_POST['DateReceived']);
    }

    if(!$error){
        $query = "INSERT INTO Projects (Project, Client, LastName, DateReceived) VALUES ('$Project', '$Client', '$LastName', '$DateReceived')";
        if($connection->query($query)){
            echo "record is successfully inserted!";
        }else{
            echo "error: record could not be inserted";
        }
    }
}
?>
<?php
    $connection->close();
?>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out. In your form you use vars that are not yet defined (Tey are defined down in the code but yout trying to echo them before defining them):

```
Project: <input type="text" name="Project" value="<?php if(isset($Project)){ echo $Project; } ?>">
    <span class="error">* <?php if(isset($ProjectErr)){ echo $ProjectErr; } ?></span>
    <br><br>
```

`isset($ProjectErr)` is never set since you setting it lower in code and also
`$ProjectErr` do not exist in your form

Solution, put form down under the php code where you checking input fields.

Edit:
Try something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang = "en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
    <title>Tech Order Department.html</title>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8" />

<style>

div {
    text-align: justify;
    }

.section {
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     width: 70%;
    }
</style>

</head>

<body>

<h2>Tech Orders</h2>

<br>

    <title>Page Title</title>

    <h2>New Project</h2>

<p class="first"><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>



<?php
function test_input($data){
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
}

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "xxx";
$password = "xxx";
$dbname = "oldga740_SeniorProject";

// create connection
$connection = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !$connection->connect_error){
    // to track errors
    $error = false;

    // now validate input fields
    if (empty($_POST['Project']) || !isset($_POST['Project'])){
        $ProjectErr = "Project name is required";
        $error = true;
    }elseif(!preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9.-]+$/",$_POST['Project'])){
        // check if project only contains number, letters, comma's periods and whitespace
        $ProjectErr = "Only letters, numbers, comma's, periods and white space allowed";
        $error = true;
    }else{
        $Project = test_input($_POST['Project']);
    }

    if (empty($_POST['Client']) || !isset($_POST['Client'])){
        $ClientErr = "Client name is required";
        $error = true;
    }elseif(!preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9.-]+$/",$_POST['Client'])){
        // check if project only contains number, letters, comma's periods and whitespace
        $ClientErr = "Only letters, numbers, comma's, periods and white space allowed";
        $error = true;
    }else{
        $Client = test_input($_POST['Client']);
    }

    if (empty($_POST['LastName']) || !isset($_POST['LastName'])){
        $LastNameErr = "Last name is required";
        $error = true;
    }elseif(!preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9-]+$/",$_POST['LastName'])){
        // check if last name only contains letters and whitespace
        $LastNameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
        $error = true;
    }else{
        $LastName = test_input($_POST['LastName']);
    }

    if (empty($_POST['DateReceived']) || !isset($_POST['DateReceived'])){
        $DateReceivedErr = "Data received field is required";
        $error = true;
    }elseif(!preg_match("/^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$/",$_POST['DateReceived'])){
        // check if data received only contains letters and whitespace
        $DateReceivedErr = "Date must be entered as YYYY/MM/DD";
        $error = true;
    }else{
        $DateReceived = test_input($_POST['DateReceived']);
    }

    if(!$error){
        $query = "INSERT INTO Projects (Project, Client, LastName, DateReceived) VALUES ('$Project', '$Client', '$LastName', '$DateReceived')";
        if($connection->query($query)){
            echo "record is successfully inserted!";
        }else{
            echo "error: record could not be inserted";
        }
    }
}
?>
<?php
    $connection->close();
?>
<form action="http://www.oldgamer60.com/Project/try.php" method="post">

    <div class="fieldset">
            <fieldset>

            Project: <input type="text" name="Project" value="<?php if(isset($Project)){ echo $Project; } ?>">
            <span class="error">* <?php if(isset($ProjectErr)){ echo $ProjectErr; } ?></span>
            <br><br>
            Client: <input type="text" name="Client" value="<?php if(isset($Client)){ echo $Client; } ?>">
            <span class="error">* <?php if(isset($ClientErr)){ echo $ClientErr; } ?></span>
            <br><br>
            LastName: <input type="text" name="LastName" value="<?php if(isset($LastName)){ echo $LastName; } ?>">
            <span class="error">* <?php if(isset($LastNameErr)){ echo $LastNameErr; } ?></span>
            <br><br>
            DateReceived: <input type="text" name="DateReceived" value="<?php if(isset($DateReceived)){ echo $DateReceived; } ?>">
            <span class="error">* <?php if(isset($DateReceivedErr)){ echo $DateReceivedErr; } ?></span>
            <br><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 
         </fieldset>
        </div>
        </form>
    <br>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I had moved the form under the php but I think I kept it inside the close connection at the bottom of the page.  I ran your edit, but I'm receiving two warnings now.  #1 Warning: mysqli::mysqli() [mysqli.mysqli]: (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'xxx'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /home/oldga740/public_html/Project/try.php on line 51
#2 Warning: mysqli::close() [mysqli.close]: Couldn't fetch mysqli in /home/oldga740/public_html/Project/try.php on line 113.  Those are my create connection and close connection lines

Comment: Thank you for your help.  That worked once I put in my database login information.

Comment: Pls don't run my code because in my code for username and password i have xxx since i dont know your credentials. Try you to move form on the bottom but to maintain html structure. Its important that php code is up top so you define vars before you use them. @Tony

Comment: Thanks again.  I'll remember that for the next time.